Trouble Adding Rings to Polygons in Vector Layers: Works Inconsistently
I am working with a SpatiaLite layer in CRS 2154 (the same as the project's CRS) with a Multi-polygon geometry type.
When I attempt to add a ring inside a polygon, it works inconsistently.
Most of the time, if the process fails, I get this message : "Could not add ring since the inserted Ring is not contained in a feature"
But creating another ring with fewer vertices, and/or a smaller ring, will resolve the issue about 90% of the time.
I have tested this on other SpatiaLite layers with Polygon geometry, on Shapefile layers, and in different projects, but the issue persists.
Here is a link to a test project where I can reproduce this issue.
Download Test project
There are no errors in the geometries in my project. No double vertices, not self-crossing geometries, no NULL geometries, etc.
I've opened an issue on Github : Link to Github issue
But I'm wondering if this is something else, as this issue would have been signaled before I guess.

Could you add some images so we understand better your issue?

The issue is due to a bug introduced in QGIS since QGIS 3.28.
You can workaround the issue just selecting the feature you need to add the ring to before using the "Add ring" map tool.
The bug has been recently fixed: the issue will no longer occur starting from QGIS LTR 3.34.12 and QGIS 3.40.0.

Layer1 is not georeferenced, it is located in the Gulf of Guinea, meaning x,y = 0,0



This is not the actual cause of the issue.
